# how can I count number of bars higher than EMA and lower than EMA - in pine?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I only want to show the number of bars that are higher and lower than the EMA21.
starting point is always crossing the EMA.
results shall be displayed in top right corner of chart pane.

What I tried is this, but I only get [1] a "1" and [2] the label is shown at the last candle, not at the top right corner of the chart:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Bars Above/Below EMA counter", overlay=true)
import TradingView/ta/5

// Input for EMA length
emaLength = input(21, title="EMA Length")

// Calculate EMA
emaValue = ta.ema(close, emaLength)

// Initialize counters
//consecutiveBarsAboveEMA = 0
//consecutiveBarsBelowEMA = 0

barsAboveEMA = 0
barsBelowEMA = 0 

// Count bars above and below EMA
//consecutiveBarsAboveEMA := close > emaValue ? consecutiveBarsAboveEMA + 1 : 0
//consecutiveBarsBelowEMA := close < emaValue ? consecutiveBarsBelowEMA + 1 : 0

if (close > emaValue)
    barsAboveEMA := barsAboveEMA + 1
    barsBelowEMA := 0
else if (close < emaValue)
    barsBelowEMA := barsBelowEMA + 1
    barsAboveEMA := 0
else
    barsAboveEMA := 0
    barsBelowEMA := 0

// Plot EMA
plot(emaValue, color=color.blue, title="EMA")

// Plot consecutive bars above and below EMA counters as labels in the top right corner
var labelAbove = label.new(na, na, text="")
var labelBelow = label.new(na, na, text="")

label.set_xy(labelAbove, bar_index, high)
label.set_xy(labelBelow, bar_index, low)

label.set_text(labelAbove, "Bars Above EMA: " + str.tostring (barsAboveEMA))
label.set_text(labelBelow, "Bars Below EMA: " + str.tostring (barsBelowEMA))

label.set_color(labelAbove, color=color.green)
label.set_color(labelBelow, color=color.red)

label.set_textcolor(labelAbove, color.white)
label.set_textcolor(labelBelow, color.white)
```

Comment: just tried this - but dunno who to display the calc values on the volume pane:                    
                                                                                                                                                
// This Pine Script™ code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
//@version=5



consecutiveHigherValues (Close >= ta.ema2(close, 21))
consecutiveLowerValues (ta.ema2(close, 21) > close) 

plot(display = consecutiveHigherValues)
plot(display = )

const plot_simple_display

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify if this isn't exactly what you're asking for, but I created an indicator to display how many bars it has been since the last cross of the EMA21:

[image: ema cross indicator]

I used this code to create the indicator:

```
//@version=5
indicator("ema cross", overlay=true)
import TradingView/ta/5

emaLength = input(21, title="ema length")

emaValue = ta.ema(close, emaLength)

var int barsSinceCross = 0
var string crossDirection = ""

crossedEMA = ta.cross(close, emaValue)

if crossedEMA // determines cross direction and counts bars since last EMA cross
    barsSinceCross := 0
    crossDirection := close > emaValue ? "above" : "below"
else
    barsSinceCross := barsSinceCross + 1

plot(emaValue, color=color.blue, title="EMA")

var label infoLabel = na
if barstate.isfirst
    infoLabel := label.new(bar_index, high, "", color=color.green, style=label.style_label_down, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
else
    label.set_text(infoLabel, "Bars Since EMA21 Cross (" + crossDirection + "): " + str.tostring(barsSinceCross))
    label.set_xy(infoLabel, bar_index, high)

label.set_y(infoLabel, ta.highest(high, 10) * 1.05) // position just off final bar
```

Pinescript unfortunately does make it easy to pin a label on any part of the chart- such as the top right- so, if there's a way to do it, I don't know how. But I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much !!!    

works fantastic and I learn a lot from this.

by the way - positioning of label also works through label.set_xy ( ...., bar index +10) for example

anyhow thank you again !